# How to Install Numix Circle Icon Pack in archLinux ?

Tags: arch-linux, icons

All I want to know is how to install Numix Circle Icon Pack on Arch Linux ? Seems like it's complex. Please explain me clearly step by step if you can.

Thanks !

Comment: It is [in the AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/numix-circle-icon-theme-git). Read the [AUR wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR) to learn how to use it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Numix circle icon theme for Arch Linux is packaged in the Arch User Repository (AUR). You may wish to read more about [the AUR and how it works](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository) before you continue. However, I will provide the steps with explanations here for reference.

1. First, visit the AUR page for [numix-circle-icon-theme-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/numix-circle-icon-theme-git/).
2. Download the tarball containing the package build by clicking "Download snapshot" in the "Package Actions" section of the page. The package will download to the default folder specified by your browser (in most cases, this is /home/*YOUR_USERNAME*/Downloads/).
3. Extract the tarball using your favorite extraction method. In this tutorial I will specify the terminal method: `cd ~/Downloads && tar xf numix-circle-icon-theme-git.tar.gz`. After this step is complete, you will be in the Downloads subdirectory of your home folder.
4. Type `cd numix-circle-icon-theme-git` to enter the subdirectory containing the extracted tarball.
5. Type `makepkg -s` in your terminal. The program will call in the PKGBUILD script for your package, download the required dependencies (the `-s` option), and proceed to make a new, XZ-compressed tarball containing the install package.
6. If you use `sudo` to manage system tasks, use step 7 instead. If not, become root with `su -`, then enter your root password. Then enter `pacman -U numix-circle-icon-theme-git-$VERSION-any.tar.xz`, where $VERSION is the package version you compiled. If you are using the BASH shell and `bash-completion` is installed and enabled for root commands, you can auto-complete the package name by pressing TAB. Follow the prompts to install the package. After a few moments, the installation will complete and you will have the Numix circle icon theme installed. After the package installs, type `exit` to leave root access.
7. If you use `sudo` to run system tasks, type `sudo pacman -U numix-circle-icon-theme-git-$VERSION-any.tar.xz` (where $VERSION is the package version you compiled), and enter your password when prompted. If you are using the BASH shell and `bash-completion` is installed and enabled in your .bashrc for `sudo` commands, you can auto-complete the package name by pressing TAB. Follow the prompts to install the package. After a few moments, the installation will complete and you will have the Numix circle icon theme installed.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use [yaourt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Yaourt) as a package management tool. It sits on top of `pacman`. With `yaourt` you have full access to the official repositories as well as access to the [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/) (Arch User Repository). The chance is high, that you find a package there (via `yaourt`).

Comment: Recommending someone use yaourt (or any AUR helper) before they understand how AUR, `makepkg` and `pacman` are related and work together is not doing them any favours...

Comment: But he will be able to install the software he wants ;)

Comment: Thanks Everyone for your ideas and solutions .. I installed Yaourt and throgh that I installed Numix Circle successfully.. :)